# jquery next all not working for inputs

Tags: jquery

Hi friends here is my code. next all is not working in jquery. when i entered the input the next all inputs must be have the same value and the previous values should not be changed. here i have written the code but when the value is given the next inputs are not getting the value. If i change the any value the next values should be changed but not previous

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.tot').change(function(){

           var tc=$(this).val();

             $(this).nextAll('.tot').each(function(){

               $(this).val(tc);

            });

         });

       });
     </script>
   </head>
  <body>
     <?php
       include('connect.php');
       $yr=$_POST['year'];
       $sm=$_POST['sem'];
       $br=$_POST['branch'];
       $sc=$_POST['sec'];
       $k=0;

       $sql="select rollno from intstd where year='$yr' and sem='$sm' and branch='$br' and sec='$sc'";
       $query=mysql_query($sql);
         echo"<table>";
             while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
             {
                 $k++;
                 $roll=$row['rollno'];
                 echo"<tr>";
                 echo"<td>$k</td>";
                 echo"<td>$roll</td>";
                 echo"<td><input type='text' class='tot' name='a[]'/></td>";
                 echo"<td><input type='text' name='b[]' /></td>";
                 echo"</tr>";
                }
              echo"</table>";
              ?>

             </body>
           </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `.nextAll()` should be applied for siblings. But in your case `.tot` is a child of `<td>`. It means you have to make a little correction like this:

```
    $('.tot').change(function(){
       var tc = $(this).val();

       $(this).parent().nextAll().find('.tot').each( function() {
           $(this).val(tc);
       });

     });
```

Note that `onchange` event fires when `input` loses focus. If you want to see changes immediately you should you `.keyup()` instead.

And I see that not every input has `.tot` class, check it.

P.S.: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o3c7gob8/1/)'s an example.

**UPD**: Working examples for all the cases with tables

1. One `<tr>` for all the `<td>`s: https://jsfiddle.net/xv2avray/4/
2. Every `<td>` has its own `<tr>`: https://jsfiddle.net/svLjg9t6/1/
3. Ultimate solution if you have any number of `<tr>`s with any number of `<td>`s with any number of `<input>`s inside: https://jsfiddle.net/mjnu1hkw/1/

Comment: not working for table. the above correction is working for div. please tell me for table

Comment: I edited your example with table replacing div in jsfiddle.  it's not working.

Comment: I showed you an example above (https://jsfiddle.net/xv2avray/4/). It works with `<td>`. But in your new case you've placed each `<td>` inside its own `<tr>` (in your question you had one `<tr>` for all the `<td>`). You changed the structure, that's why my script doesn't work. JS and HTML must work together: if you change HTML you should also correct JS. Now you have to use `.parent().parent()` or `.parents('tr')`.

Comment: So. What will be your structure? I've updated my answer. Now you have a solution for every case. And don't forget to include jQuery in your jsfiddle, these scripts don't work without jQuery (which you didn't include). So, if I helped you and everything works (it does, check the examples in the updated answer), it's time to estimate my help and mark my answer to show that the question is answered.